# Send bulk direct messages to followers using twitter API

Tags: php, twitter

New to twitter api.

Requirement:

Need to send direct messages to twitter followers of the logged user (in twitter). That is, user should be able to select his followers once he login to twitter from my site and send messages.

Is it possible to send DM in bulk ? Or any limit ? Should I need an app for this ? Any sample php code available ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you haven't thought of [googling your question](https://www.google.com/search?q=Send+bulk+direct+messages+to+followers+using+twitter+API)? There is a [250 DMs per day limit](https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following) for any Twitter account, which applies to both API and manual DMs. I suppose even if you find some way to circumvent this restriction, your approach will be frowned upon and possibly you'll get your account blocked.